# Show variation image in custom template woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created custom template for single product. But the images are not changing according to variations such as default woocommerce functionality.

```
  <div class="variation_images">
   <?php 
    wc_get_template('woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php');
    woocommerce_show_product_images();
    ?>
 </div>       

   /*below code of variations which is working fine with its 
      related price and other attributes:*/

   <?php 
                $get_variations = sizeof( $product->get_children() ) <= apply_filters( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 20, $product );
                            wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );
                            // Load the template
                            wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php', array(
                                'available_variations' => $get_variations ? $product->get_available_variations() : false,
                                'attributes'           => $product->get_variation_attributes(),
                                'selected_attributes'  => $product->get_variation_default_attributes()
                            ) );
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
                </div>
```